# In DynamoDB, How do we Update if ConditionExpression failed? Perhaps an Else expression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to do if ConditionExpression fails i will instead UpdateExpression this expression.

I am trying to do something like this, i know **ElseUpdateExpression** doesn't exist:

```
const params = {
    TableName: "Services",
    Key: {
        id: 1,
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET nextPageNumber = nextPageNumber + :incr", // increments page number if less than 99
    ElseUpdateExpression: "SET nextChapter = nextChapter + :incr",
    ConditionExpression: "nextPageNumber < :max", // Update fails if reached 99
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":incr": 1,
        ":max": 1
    },
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
};
return ddbClient.update(params).promise();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do logic like that within the database. You could however pull the item to the client first and then issue whatever appropriate update. Use optimistic concurrency control if you expect potentially multiple concurrent requests.